# iOS Simulator is not working the error code is objc[7830] in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio-3.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riwkC.png)Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
objc[7830]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x21ca5ab90) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x10443c2c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[7830]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x21ca5abe0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x10443c318). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳

```
Failed to package /Users/yashvardhan./AndroidStudioProjects/Yashvardhan.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order
warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.

Answer (score 0):

First of all run

```
flutter doctor
```

to ensure that you have no issues with you development environment.
If it looks fine try

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

and then try to run the app again.

As an additional step you can clean up the Derived data in XCode before rebuilding an app.